# ios autolayout NSConstraints conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

```
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x2831fb1e0 LMTextField:0x105836200.left == LMLoginView:0x1050429e0.left + 22.08>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x2831fbba0 LMTextField:0x105836200.right == LMLoginView:0x1050429e0.right - 22.08>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2836c1a90 LMLoginView:0x1050429e0.width == 0>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<MASLayoutConstraint:0x2831fbba0 LMTextField:0x105836200.right == LMLoginView:0x1050429e0.right - 22.08>
```

I add loginview to logincontroller's view.

````
[self.lmLoginView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.mas_equalTo(ws.aqaraLogoImgView.mas_bottom).offset(60 * kWidthScale);
         make.left.right.bottom.mas_equalTo(ws.view);
     }];```
````

Loginview is superView. it contains account input control LMTextField:0x105836200

```
    [self.accountInput mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.mas_equalTo(ws).offset(0);
        make.left.mas_equalTo(ws.mas_left).offset(20 * kWidthScale);
        make.right.mas_equalTo(ws.mas_right).offset(-20 * kWidthScale);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(40 * kWidthScale);
    }];
```

but why the constraints conflicts?  I am confused.

Comment: The best I can see is that you are giving things a `left`,`right`, and `width` constraints but the *actual* width (when only applying left and right constraints) results in a different width than *that* constraint would be. Instead of the auto layout engine leaking the width constraint, it decided to break the right constraint.....

Comment: .... you have two choices. (Keep in mind, you aren't doing anything wrong by adding constraints in the `init`, rather you are telling the layout engine to d two things that conflict.) First, you could try removing the width constraint - and I'd wager that what you'll get is a width you didn't expect! The second fix is trickier, but if you have this width constraint there for a articular reason, it will work... give your constraints priorities. This will tell the layout engine which constraint *you* prefer to break when a conflict arises.

Comment: Also, generally you should use leading and trailing, not left and right so that your layout dapto correctly to right- to-left locales

Comment: I don not add the loginview width constraint. i add left right top bottom constraints as the code show.

Answer (score -1):

I used to add constraints  to init method. I move the code to layoutSubviews method.  has no warning for constraints conflicts. but i do not kown reason.

```
-(instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self buildSubViews];
         
    }
    return self;
}
```

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```